# Is string interpolating a redirect_to notice message a security risk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, security, ruby-on-rails-3.2, brakeman

I recently ran the [Brakeman gem](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman) against my app, and one of its warnings was about a redirect line in my controller:

```
Confidence:  High
Warning type:  Redirect
Message:  Possible unprotected redirect near line xx
```

In that line in my controller, my redirect notice message includes the name of the object uploaded by the user:

```
def update
  parent_klass = params[:parent_type].constantize
  @entity = parent_klass.find params[:parent_id]

  authorize! :update, @entity

  entity_param_key = params[:parent_type].downcase.to_sym
  @entity.update_attributes params[entity_param_key]

  cache_path = begin
    if parent_klass == Clinic
      clinic_path(@entity)
    else
      specialist_path(@entity)
    end
  end
  expire_fragment cache_path

  redirect_to @entity, :notice  => "Successfully updated #{@entity.name}."
end
```

In this controller, `@entity.name` is a form value that is defined by the user, meaning someone *in theory* could try to put malicious code into this field.  However I'm unsure if using that parameter to generate a notice presents as a security risk.

Flash notice messages get presented in the view as such (in HAML):

```
#body.container
  .row
    #content.span12
      #container
        - flash.each do |type, msg|
          .alert.alert-success= msg

        = yield
```

Is this controller pattern a security risk, and if so, how can I prevent it from being a security risk while still keeping a customized notice message?

Comment: Depends on what you do with that flash message after the redirect doesn't it?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom I just added the view code.  It's pretty standard rendering of a notice message using bootstrap 2 with some modified CSS.

Comment: HAML escapes the result automatically. If you used `!=` or had some eval-type stuff in there it might be a problem, but as is, seems fine. Try putting something nasty in yourself and see what happens.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom If I was using ERB would the result also be escaped or would I need to do that manually?

Comment: with recent versions of rails your still fine. In the old days you wouldn't be.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the `:notice` value. Brakeman only looks at the first argument to `redirect_to`. Probably this is a false positive, but if you could provide a little bit more information about what's in the `@entity` value, specifically what Brakeman thinks is in `@entity`, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @Justin I updated the code.  I definitely have other security issues triggering here with brakeman but I thought they were unrelated.  As you can see the class of an `@entity` is dynamically generated on update.  This file is a controller for uploading files, and as such files can be for many different types of model classes which is why we keep the model it applies to ambiguous.  The cache method just expires the page cache to reflect the file being uploaded, I doubt it's relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is not about the flash message. I am not sure what report format you are viewing, but in the default text output you would see the dangerous value highlighted with `+` like this:

```
 redirect_to(+params[:parent_type].constantize.find(params[:parent_id])+ ...
```

in the JSON report it says

```
 "user_input": "params[:parent_type].constantize.find(params[:parent_id])",
```

The safety of the redirect relies on how well the `authorize!` method validates the `params[:parent_type].constantize` results in a valid model and (I assume) the current user is allowed to modify it. If it really results in a model, the redirect is safe.

However, the possible open redirect is the least of your worries in this method.

These lines allow an attacker to call `find` on an arbitrary class with an arbitrary argument:

```
parent_klass = params[:parent_type].constantize
@entity = parent_klass.find params[:parent_id]
```

While it's unlikely a `find` method would be that dangerous, consider the multitude of code likely included in the application and whether or not there may be some class somewhere with a `find` method that you really don't want an attacker to call.

The next bit looks like potential mass assignment:

```
entity_param_key = params[:parent_type].downcase.to_sym
@entity.update_attributes params[entity_param_key]
```

Given the lack of a `permit` call here, I can assume this application is not using strong parameters. Hopefully it is whitelisting the keys available for mass assignment using `attr_accessible`.

Also `params[:parent_type].downcase.to_sym` is a potential memory leak from the symbol creation. Normally that really isn't a huge deal in modern applications, but in this case the conversion is unnecessary since you can access `params` with symbols or strings.